# Can a No-Knowledge Proof exist?

Tags: knowledge-proof

A [Knowledge Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_knowledge) is a mechanism by which a 'prover' entity can show to a 'verifier' entity that it possesses some certain information without revealing what that specific information is (within some arbitrarily small tolerance of certainty).

Is it possible for a 'prover' to show to a 'verifier' that it **does not** possess some certain information (without the 'prover' being computationally limited, etc.)?

Comment: If a prover is being beaten with a rubber hose to force him to divulge e.g. an AES key, he may be able to convince a verifier that such a key does not exist if one in fact does not exist. Unfortunately such a proof might be exponentially long. Is that the kind of deniability you had in mind?

Comment: @KyleJones Interesting point, but not quite.  Imagine that the person with the correct AES Key had escaped, and the suspect under interrogation did not have knowledge of what the correct AES Key is.  How can the suspect prove such a thing so that he is swiftly released?  Must some other important assumptions be made in order to prove such a thing (such as a full tracking & logging of the suspect's past interactions, something more complicated, etc.)?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible unless more assumptions are made. My argument is the following. Suppose there is a proof system such that prover A who knows the secret S, fails, while B who doesn't know S succeeds. As A has more knowledge than B, it can always simulate every interaction of B, and thus succeed as well... So in order for this to make sense, there needs to be something B knows that A doesn't.

Comment: [As long as you're not interested in knowing what you've proven no knowledge of...](https://suricrasia.online/no-knowledge.html)

Comment: @c-x-berger Definitely interesting, though I don't quite understand how reversing a hash function *would* show that one doesn't have knowledge of some input.  I was originally interested in this problem because of things like criminal torture etc., so I also had 2 parties in mind, which I don't think the article addresses (though I may have missed that).

Answer (score 1):

No.  An algorithm that has access to some information can always ignore it and make decisions without looking at it, and then its externally observable behavior will be indistinguishable from an algorithm that doesn't have access to that information; so no verifier can tell the two apart.

I suggest being a bit cautious: when we talk about words like "knowledge" in the context of algorithm, we are applying some human intuition and interpretation to the underlying mathematics.  The precise meaning is given by the formal mathematical definition.

Incidentally, it's called a proof of knowledge, not a knowledge proof.

Comment: Don't worry, I understand what 'knowledge' means in this case (I am thinking of a set of tokens, but we could also use the string-in-language-interpretation).  Still, I had hoped for a bit of a more formal proof (though I shouldn't've expected one given the content of my question).